# WM_NCLBUTTONUP required from the window frame does not fire. What is the easiest Delphi fix please?

Tags: delphi, resize, message, frame

I need an event to fire when the use stops changing the size of a window, i.e by releasing the mouse on the frame. I've tried WM_NCLBUTTONUP but this does not fire - I presume because there are lots of complaints about it not working. Has anyone got an example of how I can work around this please? I simply need to know when a resize has ended. Thanks

Comment: It is *[documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* that `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` will not be posted when the mouse is captured. The mouse has to be captured while moving/sizing, because it may be out of window area (the mouse have to be moved first to have the window moved/sized).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Listen for [`WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632623%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Works pefectly David, thanks. From the description of the message I would not have thought it was applicable - it does not seem that the window is in a 'modal' state to me.

Comment: sizing and moving operations, just like showing menus, are very much modal operations. Try doing some other UI action in the middle of a window resize.